# STDIN_FILENO undeclared in Windows

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, stdin

I have some code using the select function that compiles and runs fine in Linux. But I'm trying to port it to Windows and am getting this error I don't know how to deal with. It says

```
STDIN_FILENO: undeclared identifier
```

I haven't been able to come up with or find any solution for this. Is there a way to make STDIN_FILENO work in Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STDIN_FILENO is a definition of standard POSIX,

Try 0 !

Comment: consider to write a macro - #define STDIN_LINENO 0

Comment: typo alert. STDIN_FILENO not STDIN_LINENO :)

Answer (score 6):

[MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx) the use of `_fileno(stdin)`, where `_fileno` is declared in `<stdio.h>`.

Note, however:

> If **stdout** or **stderr** is not associated with an output stream (for example, in a Windows application without a console window), the file descriptor returned is -2. In previous versions, the file descriptor returned was -1. This change allows applications to distinguish this condition from an error.

Comment: If `_fileno()` isn't defined, try `fileno()`.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for answering so late, but I have solved this problem adding `unistd.h` on gcc compiler. So, try to add

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Useful reference [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html).

Comment: Please note that there is no <unistd.h> on Microsoft Windows so you can't just #include it.